# Drawing from a vector of objects using sfml

Tags: c++, oop, c++17, sfml

I have a class named Particle and i want to create a vector of particles. The problem is that my code is not drawing the objects stored in the vector. I tried different implementations, the first one was:
`std::vector<Particle> particles(10);`
and then i filled the vectors:
`for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) particles.emplace_back(new Particle(false));`
for drawing i used:
`for(const auto& x: particles) window.draw(x);`
the problem is that this is drawing just one object. Then i tried to create a class of particles container with a vector of shared_ptr:
`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle>> particle_container;`
And the problem is the same, it just draws one particle, i don't know if theres something wrong with my implementation of the class particle or something wrong in the waay i use the draw function of sfml. This is my Particle class:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
using namespace sf;
class Particle : public sf::Drawable{
    sf::CircleShape particle;
    Vector2f position; //current position of the particle
    Vector2f velocity;  //velocity of the particle
    double radius; //radius of each particle
    double mass; //mass of the particle
    int count; //number of collisions of each particle
    bool sick; //if the particle is infected
    Color color; //color of the particle
public:
    //constructors
    Particle(Vector2f _position, Vector2f _velocity, double _radius, double _mass, bool _sick);
    Particle(bool sick);
}:
```

the Particle.cpp:

```
#include "Particle.h"

template<class T>
double Rand(T first, T last) {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::default_random_engine eng(dev());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dis(first, last);
    return dis(eng);
}

Particle::Particle(Vector2f _position, Vector2f _velocity, double _radius, double _mass, bool _sick) {
    position = _position;
    velocity = _velocity;
    radius = _radius;
    mass = _mass;
    sick = _sick;

    if(sick) color = sf::Color::Green;
    else color = sf::Color::Red;

    //giving values to the particle
    particle.setPosition(position);
    particle.setRadius(radius);
    particle.setFillColor(color);
}

Particle::Particle(bool sick) {
    position.x = Rand(0.0, 550.0);
    position.y = Rand(0.0, 550.0);
    velocity.x = Rand(-0.005, 0.005);
    velocity.y = Rand(-0.005, 0.005);
    radius = 2.0;
    mass = 0.5;

    if(sick) color = sf::Color::Green;
    else color = sf::Color::Red;

    particle.setPosition(position);
    particle.setRadius(radius);
    particle.setFillColor(color);
}
```

And this is the particles_container

```
class particles_container : public sf::Drawable {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle>> particle_container;
    //std::vector<Particle> particle_container;
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &renderTarget, sf::RenderStates renderStates) const;
public:
    //default constructor
    particles_container();

    //constructor with a number of given particles
    explicit particles_container(size_t size);

    //default destructor
    ~particles_container() override;

    //returns the container
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle>> getContainer();

    //another function to draw
    void drawContainer(sf::RenderWindow &window);
};
```

the particles_container.cpp:

```
void particles_container::draw(RenderTarget &renderTarget, sf::RenderStates renderStates) const {
    for (const auto & i : particle_container) {
        renderTarget.draw(*i);
    }
}

particles_container::particles_container(size_t size) {
    if(size > 0){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) particle_container.emplace_back(new Particle(false));
    }
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle>> particles_container::getContainer() {
    return particle_container;
}

void particles_container::drawContainer(RenderWindow &window) {
    for (auto & i : particle_container) {
        window.draw(*i);
    }
}
```

and finally this is my main.cpp:

```
#include "Particle.h"
#include "particles_container.h"
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode (600, 600), "PF");
    std::vector<Particle> particles(10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) particles.emplace_back(new Particle(false));
    Particle p1(sf::Vector2f(45.0,45.0), sf::Vector2f(0.01,0.005), 2, 0.5, false);
    particles_container parts(100);
    Particle p3(true);
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Particle> > my_vector(10);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) my_vector.emplace_back(new Particle(false));

    while(window.isOpen()){
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        //parts.drawContainer(window);
        //window.draw(parts);
        for(const auto& x: particles) window.draw(x);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

this is the output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89HAX.png)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I am using:
SFML 2.5.1 and c++17

Comment: Welcome to SO! You draw by `window.display()`, but you don't show its code, nor any code to trace which `Particle` is rendered when. We can't look for the issue.

Comment: Not the real problem but `std::vector<Particle> particles(10)` already constructs a vector with 10 default-initialized Particles. No need to then push another 10 Particles on top of it. Also, use `make_shared<Particle>(false)` instead of passing `new Particle` to `emplace_back`.

Comment: Sorry, that function is implemented in the sfml library. should i post that code to? because i don't know  if i can edit that.

Comment: thanks for the advices Botje

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try building it up from something simpler. You probably don't need to use `std::shared_ptr` - just store the particles directly, as you were doing previously (note the comment above about how you're using `std::vector` though). Start by just rendering a couple of particles by brute force, as individual objects (not in a vector). Then put them in a vector and render them 'manually', one at a time. Then try them in a loop, and so on. Keep going until it stops working (if it does). I think this approach will be likely to reveal where the problem lies.

Comment: I did that, i tried everything but i never thought it would be something with the Rand function. Anyways thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Rand` function constructs a new random device every time, which has a high probability to always return the same number sequence. Move the construction of `dev` out of your `Rand` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. That was the problem.